# TimeZone problem with Oracle SQL Developer for Windows on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, oracle-sql-developer, timezone

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using **Oracle SQL Developer**, but I get this error: *Status: fail, test failed:*

> Estado: Fallo:Fallo de la prueba: The server time zone value 'PDT' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

According to [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515700/mysql-jdbc-driver-5-1-33-time-zone-issue) I should use a connection string such as the following, to override the server TimeZone definition.

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql.server:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC
```

But I cannot find where to define a connection string on Oracle SQL Developer. I only get this screen when configuring (or changing configuration):
[image: Oracle SQL Developer configuration string]

(In my test it says `localhost` but I am doing an SSH tunnel to a remote server.)

There is no way to add extra parameters such as `serverTimezone` from the configuration box.

Some other solutions propose to create a map of timezones (v.g. mapping `PDT` to `Americas/Los_Angeles`).

I cannot find a Java control. It is supposed to be integrated within Oracle SQL Developer. I just cannot find any place I can add any extra configuration. I don't have administrative privileges in the server. I might change to some other MySQL client (I can actually work fine with PHPMyAdmin), but I also need to test on Oracle Servers.

Answer (score 2):

I found the following solution on a forum (https://community.oracle.com/thread/4144569?start=0)

You have to just insert a string in the port value
`PORT_NUM?SERVEROPTIONS&dummyparam=` and leave the database field empty

if you need to specify the database name, you just have to use this other string (I suppose, not tested)
`PORT_NUM/DB_NAME?SERVEROPTIONS&dummyparam=`

Hope this is still relevant to you or maybe someone

Comment: just to add that i tested this solution and worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Developer, there is a connection hack that worked for me when there was a timezone mismatch between the client and server. (In my case I could not modify the server parameters.) The hack exploits the fact that the Port field is just appended to the connection URL as a string. So something like this works:

**3306/?serverTimezone=America/Winnipeg&dummyparam=**

I needed the dummyparam= at the end to protect against URL format errors when the trailing slash gets appended.